# How to echo value from different page?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a table like this :

[image: table]

When I click update link, I want to echo the "nim" column (first column) to this page inside the nim input text.

[image]

Here is my controller

```
public function fupdate() {     
        $this->load->view('update_form_mhs');
}

public function update() {
}
```

Here is my view:

```
<tr>
    <td>NIM</td>                    
    <td><input type="text" placeholder="enter nim" name="nim"></td>
</tr>
```

How do I echo that?

Comment: fetch data first from table with sql query, then pass that data $this->load->view('update_form_mhs',$data);@MochamadRamdannyLukman

Comment: how to fetch the data?

Answer (score 1):

You can send data from the listing page through `GET` method like:

```
<a href="xyz.php?nim=9004">9004</a>
```

And in the form page,

get `nim` through `$_GET['nim']`

So, the corrected code:

```
<td><input type="text" placeholder="enter nim" name="nim" value="<?php echo $_GET['nim']?>"/></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the update method you need to do the following:

- Grab the ID from the URL, which I assume is the number at the end of the update link (4441 in this case).
- Fetch the row from the database which corresponds to this ID.
- Echo out the details from that single row into the HTML code where you want it.

Now, since you haven't posted any code which relates to the actual fetching of the data, I'm afraid I cannot help you further with that. However, this step is pretty basic and should be well documented in the CI manual.